# How to display current user's custom property in a View

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Using [ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=vs0) I can display the current user's name as follows. I've created a custom property of the users as `FullName`. I can use this property in controller such as: `_userManager.Users.Where(u => u.FullName == "Bob Doe")` etc. But, in a View, I'm not able to display this property. For example, the `Intellisense` does not recognize `@User.Identity.FullName`.

**View**

```
...
@User.Identity.Name
....
```

Comment: The `User` in your view isn't in any way related to the `User` in your Identity! `_userManager.Users` is likely `ApplicationUser`, whereas your `User` in your View is the `IPrincipal` from `HttpContext.User`...

Comment: @Tseng So, can I still get custom property in View in one way or the other?

Comment: Well, if you want to access the property of your **database** model you need to pass the model to the view (or create a view Model and pass it there). But `Httpcontext.User` doesn't have any custom properties, only the ones the identity offers + a list of **claims**